# Desativar SecurityComponent - CakePHP + Croogo

Tags: php, cakephp, plugin

estou desenvolvendo um plugin para o Croogo, e preciso criar apenas mais um campo text, aos nodes.

O campo aparece nas abas dos Nodes e está ok, mas meu problema é quando estou salvando os dados, aparece uma mensagem de erro de segurança:

> Erro de Segurança
>
> O endereço solicitado não foi encontrado neste servidor.
>
> Requisição perdida devido a violação de "auth"

Seria possível desabilitá-lo com:

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions[] = 'admin_toggle';
```

Porém, não é possível fazer isso direto no **Nodes/NodesController.php**, pois o Croogo é instalado via composer, então preciso fazer isso por meio do meu plugin. Mas como?